# Rubyの二重while文が上手く機能しない

Tags: ruby

こんばんは。
今Rubyで簡単な「掛け算の表」を作るのに挑戦しています。
ですが、Rubyの二重whileが期待した出力をしません。自分なりにRubyのリファレンスでwhileの項目を見たり、Rubyの解説サイトでwhileの欄を見たりして色々弄ってみましたが上手くいきませんでした。

自分が書いたコードはこんな感じです(使ってる言葉とか間違ってたり、コードが汚かったら申し訳ありません)
[image: コード]

問題の出力はこんなかんじです
[image: 出力]

ご覧の通り1の段だけ出ていて2~9の段が出力されません...。

自分なりに理解してるプログラムの流れは
まず`x = 1 y = 1`で変数の初期化をしています。(1の段とかける数1から始めたいから)

```
while x <= 9 do
```

は`x = 1`で条件式がtrueなので処理に入ります。
まず最初の処理は

```
while y <= 9 do
```

で、whileの中にwhileを作った形になってます。
条件式`y <= 9`のwhile文で1*1 ~ 1*9までの結果が出力に出るはずです。
無限ループを防ぐため`y += 1`。
この内側のwhileがfalseになって初めて、`puts`が実行され、改行されます。(次の段を表示するため)
最後に次の段の計算をしたいので`x += 1`で段を進めてます。

それでまた`while x <= 9 do`に来て、条件式がtrueになるので同じ処理が続いてくはずです。

なのに出力結果は1の段しか出ません....

凄く下手で見辛い質問で申し訳ありません。
自分なりに格闘して探ってみたのですが、解決できません。どうかよろしくおねがいします

Comment: すみません、期待する出力を書いてませんでした...。

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9　　2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18

Comment: y の値を 1 に戻す処理が必要ですね:-)

Comment: すみませんコメントで改行が使えずおかしなことになってます...

Comment: あああ！なるほど！　yを1に初期化する作業がいるんですね！　実はnode.jsでも同じことしてたんですが、for文は()内に変数の初期化が最初からついてるので全くRubyで意識していませんでした....　ありがとうございます！

Comment: ちゃんと出ました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: うまく行った経緯を回答にしてみてはどうでしょう。このサイトでは自己回答は奨励されていますし、自己回答を承認する事もできます。

Comment: 変数yを変えるだけでしたが、アドバイス通り自己回答に挑戦してみます(^.^) ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

変数をaからbまで1ずつ増やしながらループさせる場合、大抵の言語ではもっと適した制御構造があるので、そちらを使いましょう。rubyであれば

```
(1..9).each do |x|
  (1..9).each do |y|
     ...
  end
end
```

Comment: せっかく回答してくださったのに返信が遅れてしまい申し訳ありません。　こちらのほうがスッキリしていて目から鱗です！　早速試してみます!ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

while文は条件式だけ書くので、このままだと次の段に行った時に変数yの値が10のままになり、変数yが1に初期化されない。(他言語でfor文を使う場合、for文内に変数初期化がある) 
つまり、内側の`while y <= 9 do`のwhile文は変数yが10なので、falseになり、このように1の段の結果しか処理されない。

解決法としては

```
while x <= 9 do
  while y <= 9 do
   print((x*y).to_s + "")
   y += 1
  end
  puts
  #変数yを1に戻す
  y = 1 
  x += 1
end
```

とする。yの初期化を加えるだけ

Comment: 3行目を、6行目と7行目の間に持ってくると...

Comment: すごい！たしかにできました！ありがとうございます。3行目で変数を宣言するよりwhile内でやったほうが確かにスマート(?)ですね！

Comment: 変数スコープというキーワードで調べてみると良いと思います。